# Prove or disprove: $f$ is an injection iff $\exists g \forall x\ g(f(x)) = x$ ($f$ and $g$ are total functions from D to D)

Tags: discrete-mathematics, solution-verification

## Problem

> Let $f:D \to D$ be a total function from some non-empty set $D$ to itself. $x$ and $y$ are variables ranging over $D$, and $g$ is a variable ranging over total functions from $D$ to $D$. Determine whether or not the proposition $\exists g \forall x\ g(f(x)) = x$ is equivalent to the proposition that $f$ is an injection.

## Attempt

I claim that the proposition $\exists g \forall x\ g(f(x)) = x$ is equivalent to the proposition that $f$ is an injection.

Proof:

1. First, I show one direction of the equivalence: If $\exists g \forall x\ g(f(x)) = x$, then $f$ is injective.

   I will show it by contrapositive: If $f$ is not injective, then, for every $g$, there must be an $x$ such that $g(f(x)) \neq x$.

   Assume $f$ is not injective, and $g$ is any total function from $D$ to $D$.

   Since $f$ is not injective, there must be $x_0,x_1,y_0 \in D$ such that $x_0 \neq x_1$ and $f(x_0) = f(x_1) = y_0$. Then, we have that:

   $g(f(x_0)) = g(y_0)$ and $g(f(x_1)) = g(y_0)$.

   Note that, since $g$ is total, we know that $g(y_0)$ exists.

   From the above, $g(f(x_0)) = g(f(x_1))$.

   To show that this implies that there must be an $x$ such that $g(f(x)) \neq x$, there are two cases:

   - Case 1.1. If $x_0 \neq g(y_0)$, then $g(f(x_0)) = g(y_0) \neq x_0$. So, $x_0$ is an $x$ such that $g(f(x)) \neq x$.
   - Case 1.2. If $x_0 = g(y_0)$, then $g(f(x_1)) = g(y_0) = x_0$. However, since $x_0 \neq x_1$, this means that $g(f(x_1)) \neq x_1$. So, $x_1$ is an $x$ such that $g(f(x)) \neq x$.

   So, either way, there is an $x$ such that $g(f(x)) \neq x$.
2. Now, I show the other direction of the equivalence: If $f$ is injective, then $\exists g \forall x\ g(f(x)) = x$.

   Assume $f$ is total and injective. I will construct a $g$ such that $g$ is total and $\forall x\ g(f(x)) = x$.

   First, note that, since $f$ is total and injective, $f^{-1}$ is a surjective function, and $f^{-1}(x) = x$ for all $x$ in $f(D)$.

   So, for all $x$ where $f^{-1}(x)$ is defined, $g$ can be defined as $f^{-1}(x)$. However, $f^{-1}$ is not necessarily total, and $g$ needs to be total. To complete the definition of $g$, we need to define it for all $x \in D$ for which $f^{-1}(x)$ is not defined. For example, we can define $g(x) = x$ for all $x$ such that $f^{-1}(x)$ is not defined.

   So, $g$ can be constructed as:

   $g = \left\{\begin{matrix}f^{-1}(x) & \text{ if }f^{-1}(x)\text{ is defined}\\x & \text{ if }f^{-1}(x)\text{ is not defined}\end{matrix}\right.$

Is this correct? Thank you in advance.

Comment: (I didn't check every detail but) the approach is definitely sound!

Comment: $\exists g \forall x\ g(f(x)) = x$ is equivalent to saying that $f$ is an injection is false because the left hand side is not equivalent to an utterance.

Comment: @WilliamElliot - Amended that by changing "to saying that" to "to the proposition that".

Comment: The second part requires a puesdo  inverse function which has been hand waved into existence.

Comment: Mathematically, total functions are not considered.  Functions are defined for the domain, all of it.  They're  an annoying computer think thing.  By computhink, all functions are not total simply by adding an element to the domain.

Answer (score 0):

Streamlined proof.

Assume for all x, g(f(x)) = x.
If f(x) = f(y), then x = g(f(x)) = g(f(y)) = y.
Thus f is an injection.

Assume f is an injection.
Define g:range f -> domain f.
If y in range f, then exists x with y = f(x).
Set g(y) = x.
Prove this is well defined using the fact that f is injective.
Show for all x, g(f(x)) = x.

Comment: Yes, except that you ignored the requirement on the domains.

Comment: Total functions are a computer think think.   Thus irreverent to mathematical problems.  @AndrésE.Caicedo

Comment: No, I think you are just showing the boundaries of your knowledge in an ugly way. Anyway, the problem requires both $f$ and $g$ to have the same domain $D$ and for both to have range contained in $D$.